# Conflict using <tx:annotation-driven and <aop:aspectj-autoproxy

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop

I have been facing issue with following spring configuration. When i use txn:annotation alone it works fine, but when i try to use AOP it is causing exception.

Part of Spring config file:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  
      proxy-target-class="true"/>   
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy   >
   <aop:include name="logging"/>
 </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
 <bean id="dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
 ....
 </bean>
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">
 </bean>
<!--Aspect Annotation class-->
<bean id="logging" class="com.aop.LoggingAspect"></bean>
 <!--Rest only other simple Business/DAO beans-->
```

Exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' has been injected into other beans [org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I might be wrong at spring configuration, Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your beans definitions but it looks like you have circular dependencies. Because the names of the beans suggest that the problem occurs in spring beans and not your beans I guess you're defining things in a way that causes the problem. My guess is that you have some of your definitions defined in an XML and some defined with annotations.
For example - you define a class with `@Transactional` annotation and for the same class you define an aspect using XML.

Comment: Thanks. Please see updated spring config file. I am not able to see any such case here but still i am getting the same error.